# How to restore only a specific system state item in Windows Server

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, backup-restoration

i have two Windows server in 2012 version, i want backup specific system state item in the first server and recover it on the second server but retaining  the roles and system state existents in the second server before the recovery.

How to recover some the specific roles and features in the second server without override the actual roles and features and system state?

Comment: Are you trying to use the backup system to recover information not available on production servers or to replicate information available on one server to another server? If that latter, you might look for another way.

Comment: I'm trying to use the backup system state for only few items like Active directory or certificate services  on first server  to recover it on second server but retaining the system state items, roles and services from second server ie restore but without override another roles or services.

Comment: And the "first server" is lost and no longer available? Why not completely restore the first server? If it the first server is not lost, why not just use AD replication? It might be that those are your only two options that will work.

Comment: Yes, the first server is no longer available, I just need to backing 2 or 3 features to recover in the second server available and not lose all my features in the second server